# Java GUI and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a GUI which has textarea and buttons and etc.........

I have a different class which is a thread that is running constantly. I want to append text to the textarea when certain conditions are met in the thread class.

In the class containing the textarea i have getter methods for the textarea. I have also declared that class(containing the textarea) as a variable in the thread class.

I try to call the get method of the textarea on the variable and afterwards the append() method, but the textarea doesn't update itself.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to change the title to something more related to the question. That way people viewing the listing will know what's the question about.

Comment: The "append" method is thread safe. So if you don't see the text in the GUI then you don't have a proper reference to the text area that is visible. Maybe you created two text areas by mistake. Try adding a System.out.println( textArea.getText() ) so you can see if you are appending text to the visible text area.

Answer (score 5):

The main point is that you have to care about following guidelines given by Sun according to thread management with Swing, you can have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html).

What you will understand is that you have to dispatch GUI related events with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(..)` according to your specific case. This because GUI events are managed by the *Event Dispatching Thread* and you shouldn't manage them in your own threads..

Comment: Some of the Swing documentation (less in JDK 7...) states that certain methods are thread-safe. Such comments often do not agree with the implementation, or any possible implementation. Also code attempting to use such methods in a threaded way will likely have thread bugs of its own.

Answer (score 1):

You must not call UI methods from a non-UI thread. To call methods from a non-UI thread, you must a UI specific method which says "send a piece of code to the UI thread for execution". In SWT, this is `Display.getDefault().asyncExec(Runnable)`. For Swing, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

See [this article](http://java-gui.info/Wiley-Professional.Java.Interfaces.with.SWT.JFace/12093/BBL0022.html) for more information.